# Remove SHA1 ciphers from NGNIX

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

After referencing [this blog](https://grumpytechie.net/2020/04/22/disabling-insecure-ciphers-on-nginx-nginx-tricks-part-4/), I updated the configuration for my website as follows:

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
```

But while testing with [testssl.sh](https://testssl.sh/), some SHA1 ciphers are present too which can be seen in following output

```
Hexcode  Cipher Suite Name (OpenSSL)       KeyExch.   Encryption  Bits     Cipher Suite Name (IANA/RFC)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSLv2
 - 
SSLv3
 - 
TLSv1
 - 
TLSv1.1
 - 
TLSv1.2 (server order)
 xc030   ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384       ECDH 253   AESGCM      256      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384              
 xcca8   ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305       ECDH 253   ChaCha20    256      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256        
 xc061   ECDHE-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384          ECDH 253   ARIAGCM     256      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_ARIA_256_GCM_SHA384             
 xc02f   ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256       ECDH 253   AESGCM      128      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256              
 xc060   ECDHE-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256          ECDH 253   ARIAGCM     128      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_ARIA_128_GCM_SHA256             
 xc028   ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384           ECDH 253   AES         256      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384              
 xc077   ECDHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA384      ECDH 253   Camellia    256      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA384         
 xc027   ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256           ECDH 253   AES         128      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256              
 xc076   ECDHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256      ECDH 253   Camellia    128      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256         
 xc014   ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA              ECDH 253   AES         256      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                 
 xc013   ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA              ECDH 253   AES         128      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA                 
 x9d     AES256-GCM-SHA384                 RSA        AESGCM      256      TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384                    
 xc0a1   AES256-CCM8                       RSA        AESCCM8     256      TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8                         
 xc09d   AES256-CCM                        RSA        AESCCM      256      TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM                           
 xc051   ARIA256-GCM-SHA384                RSA        ARIAGCM     256      TLS_RSA_WITH_ARIA_256_GCM_SHA384                   
 x9c     AES128-GCM-SHA256                 RSA        AESGCM      128      TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256                    
 xc0a0   AES128-CCM8                       RSA        AESCCM8     128      TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8                         
 xc09c   AES128-CCM                        RSA        AESCCM      128      TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM                           
 xc050   ARIA128-GCM-SHA256                RSA        ARIAGCM     128      TLS_RSA_WITH_ARIA_128_GCM_SHA256                   
 x3d     AES256-SHA256                     RSA        AES         256      TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256                    
 xc0     CAMELLIA256-SHA256                RSA        Camellia    256      TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA256               
 x3c     AES128-SHA256                     RSA        AES         128      TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256                    
 xba     CAMELLIA128-SHA256                RSA        Camellia    128      TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256               
 x35     AES256-SHA                        RSA        AES         256      TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                       
 x84     CAMELLIA256-SHA                   RSA        Camellia    256      TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA                  
 x2f     AES128-SHA                        RSA        AES         128      TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA                       
 x41     CAMELLIA128-SHA                   RSA        Camellia    128      TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA                  
TLSv1.3 (server order)
 x1302   TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384            ECDH 253   AESGCM      256      TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384                             
 x1303   TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256      ECDH 253   ChaCha20    256      TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256                       
 x1301   TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256            ECDH 253   AESGCM      128      TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

How can I remove SHA1 ciphers from this list?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
```